# TikZ: Very high document gives 'Dimension too large'

Tags: tikz-pgf, dimensions

I have a problem, that my document becomes to high, if I set N=118 nodes with 
`below=7cm of \N.north` --->

```
! Dimension too large.
```

---> What could I do?`

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[border=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, fill=yellow}]
\node[](0){}; % seems to be needed
\foreach[
count=\n from 0, evaluate={\N={\n>0 ? int(\n-1) : \n}}
] \tablerow in {1,2,...,117}{
\node[anchor=north, 
below=7cm of \N.north, % works not, but wanted
%below=1cm of \N.north, % works
](\n){\n};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\documentclass{article}` work OK

Comment: I don't think so. Just test the 'wanted'-version, see above.

Comment: Ha, now I see the problem :)

Comment: Try `\the\dimexpr117\dimexpr7cm\relax\relax`. That will result in a dimension too large as well. TeX's maximum dimension is 16383.99998pt (that's roughly 5.75 metre) and 7cm equals 199.16928pt. 117*7cm is ca. 23302.80576pt, which is more than TeX can handle.

Comment: Mmmhh... So, I have to do it completely different.

Comment: Using only digits as the node name is not a good idea. It's way too easy to upset the parser this way.